# Capital and Lowercase Acronyms

Tags: grammar, abbreviations, capitalization

Why is the acronym for sport utility vehicle (SUV) capitalized but for miles per gallon (mpg) it is lowercased?

Comment: Acronyms which are "pronounceable" (**SUV, CAT** scan, **PIN** number,...) are much more likely to be capitalised than **mpg, rpm,  cpu,...** This is a convenience to the *reader,* - who needs to recognise if something is an acronym rather that a "normal" word. Obviously he doesn't normally need any such help to realise that those lower-case acronyms can't possibly be normal words.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - does anyone say 'suv', rhyming with 'love', I guess? I only hear ess-you-vee.

Comment: It's essentially American, so I'd rarely *hear* it anyway. But I don't know of any consistent principle explaining why CAT scans and PIN numbers are usually pronounced as if they were words, but [SUV vehicles](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22suv+vehicles%22) are usually "spelled" out. Unless it's just that cat and pin are *already* words (and I can't think of some similar terms that either are or aren't words as well as acronyms, to check that one out! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I can think of Nasa, Nato, the Baftas, ASCII, Unicef, and the Americans have POTUS, FLOTUS, and SCOTUS that are not words. Nobody said BOAC as 'boke', which might have been due to their smooth flights. I note that many UK style guides prefer e.g. Nasa to NASA, etc.

Comment: I'm not great at getting NGrams to do calculations, but I *think* [this AmE chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28NASA%29%2F%28Nasa%29&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) and [this BrE chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28NASA%29%2F%28Nasa%29&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) are telling us that fully-capitalised **NASA** is 10 times more likely (relative to **Nasa**) in the AmE corpus than the BrE one. (Or maybe it's just that Americans refer to nasa more often than Brits, I dunno! :)

Answer (score -2):

**Acronyms** - stand for a series of words, e.g. SUV = Sports Utility Vehicle

**Units** - When there is a series of letters indicating units of measurement, the decision about whether to capitalise or not depends on how the unit is conventionally written on  its own.

m = miles, p = per, h = hour ---> miles per hour = mph

m = metres, / = per, s = second  ---> m/s

joules = **J**, / = per, second = s ---> joule per second = **J**/s

milli = m, electron = e, volt = V ---> milli-electronvolt = meV

Mega = M, electron = e, volt = V --->  Mega-electronvolt = MeV

Comment: Any car dashboard I see has MPH and not mph.